# Multiple Selects With One Column Encrypted

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do two select statements on the same table. However I get errors. The reason for this query is one of the columns is 256 bit CRC encrypted. Here is my query:

```
SELECT (select COLUMNA from TABLE) AS 'NumberA',
(select CAST(aes_decrypt(COLUMNB,'key','IV') AS CHAR) from TABLE) AS 'Number2';
```

This query throws this error:

```
Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Both of these selects by themselves work fine. However I need to figure out how to select all of the columns and use the encrypted column in the query as well.

Also, if you can't answer the question, don't put it on hold. Just state you don't know the answer

Comment: Voting to put it on hold because it is a duplicate. Please try to reopen the one put on hold, do not open a new one.

Comment: Then someone answer the original

Comment: @skinfrakki That's not an attitude that's going to help you get advice. Try [being nice](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) and following the site guidelines.

Comment: I did. And I waited for days on my first question. How a question that involves a query of multiple columns with one being encrypted not a related topic is something that I can't understand

Comment: Basic SQL questions are not always considered [on topic](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, and your question is [on hold](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it probably "has a typo, basic error, or is not relevant to most of our audience." Feel free to edit the original to get the hold taken off if you feel as though you can provide new info to change this assessment of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue is concerning the encryption. You are doing two sub-queries either of which could contain multiple rows, hence the error. If both source tables are the same, you can re-write as: -

```
SELECT COLUMNA AS 'NumberA',
CAST(aes_decrypt(COLUMNB,'key','IV') AS CHAR) AS 'Number2'
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Perfect! Yes that's what it was. I kept putting select in front of CAST! Thank you!

Comment: @skinfrakki You do realize that's what I put in the other question, right? That's why it was put on hold.